# SQL statement with conditional where clause

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that i would like to filter on a particular data_src column where it can have the following possible values:

```
data_src data   users
srcA     x      user1
srcB     y      user1
srcC     z      user2
NULL     NULL   user2
```

Let's say these data_src have different data qualities: srcA > srcB > srcC > NULL

In my query, i only want to return the highest data quality for each user. So my query would produce:

```
data_src data   users
srcA     x      user1
srcC     z      user2
```

Also assume the order srcA, srcB, srcC cannot be sorted by alphanumeric order, but I do know the right order is srcA, srcB, srcC. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Consider case expression `case when data_Src = 'SrcA' then 1 when 'srcC' then 2 end  but I don't see how X is > y for user 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from table
qualify row_number() over (partition by users order by something_sortable) = 1
```

is how you do it if you have something that is "sortable" but if the there is no storability, you can go for random via `order by true`

So if we have a known rank conversion,

```
with table_name(data_src,data,users) as (
    select * from values
    ('srcA', 'x   ', 'user1'),
    ('srcB', 'y   ', 'user1'),
    ('srcC', 'z   ', 'user2'),
    (NULL, NULL, 'user2')
)
select *,
    case data_src when 'srcA' then 0 when 'srcB' then 1 when 'srcC' then 2 else 256 end as rank
from table_name
--qualify row_number() over (partition by users order by rank ) = 1
```

you can take the lowest value per partition item/s

| DATA_SRC | DATA | USERS | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| srcA | x | user1 | 0 |
| srcB | y | user1 | 1 |
| srcC | z | user2 | 2 |
| null | user2 | 256 |  |

for small rank functions it can be pushed inline into the qualify

```
with table_name(data_src,data,users) as (
    select * from values
    ('srcA', 'x   ', 'user1'),
    ('srcB', 'y   ', 'user1'),
    ('srcC', 'z   ', 'user2'),
    (NULL, NULL, 'user2')
)
select *
from table_name
qualify row_number() over (partition by users order by case data_src when 'srcA' then 0 when 'srcB' then 1 when 'srcC' then 2 else 256 end ) = 1
```

gives:

| DATA_SRC | DATA | USERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| srcA | x | user1 |
| srcC | z | user2 |

Comment: my data quality string cannot be sorted by order by, as I mentioned in the Q. Say you sort it with order by, then it comes srcC, srcA, srcB.

Comment: Yes, I get you mentioned `data quality string` cannot be used. So use something else. And if you have nothing, use random, or do nothing. The choices are yours

Comment: if your question is `how do a do a stable sort on data that is not comparable on the order I want, and I none of my data reflects the order I want` then you don't have an answerable question.

Comment: which is to say, there are two question here, "how to get just one row" and "how to sort data", I have not answered the latter, as there is not details to help with this.

Comment: No...I know the right priority order...it is srcA, srcB, srcC, NULL. So if you want to explicily define the priority as srcA, srcB, srcC, NULL in your query, i can take the answer. I am just saying dont use the alphanumeric sorting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Simeon is correct. You need some kind of "priority" associated with the `data_src`.  You can create a new table with `data_src` and join to the table to use a `priority` column.

If the list of `data_src` is well known and finite you could create a CTE to hardcode the priority.  Just be careful with `NULL`s. I believe Snowflake has the ability to be ["NULL Safe"](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/equal_null.html) when it comes to equality comparisons if you want to go that direction.

See fiddle below (It's in SQL Server but the idea should be pretty easily translatable to Snowflake).  It's unfortunate that SQL Server doesn't have the `qualify` statement.

https://dbfiddle.uk/3SSwHoYp